# Scrapy различный html в разный момент времени

Tags: python, scrapy

Кратко не могу изложить суть проблемы, потому что искренне не понимаю в чем именно заключается она, могу лишь озвучить свои наблюдения и попытаться получить тут хоть какие-то подсказки.

Есть сайт брендовой косметики http://iledebeaute.ru. Есть рабочий код для обхода каталога и вытягивания всей инфы из оного. Проблема заключается в том, что в n-ном количестве случаем в ответ приходит пустота по селекторам. И только по ним, т.е. половина инфы вырывается регуляркой из JSON-а на странице и с ней всё в порядке. При чем проблемные товары каждый раз разные, закономерность не проследил.

Вот что я пробовал делать:
 - Собирал постманом куки со страницы и руками пересы
 - Пробовал менять свой локальный ip, подключал crawlera в облаке скрапингхаба. (в принципе, это было бы актуально для случаев, когда товары переставали бы собираться на определенном моменте из-за бана ip, но тут именно выборочно и хаотично)
 - Записывал HTML в файлик. Вот тут и началась мистика, с ним всё в порядке, вот реально всё в порядке. Делал второй файлик, в него записывал только данные по селектору, в духе "//*" или "//html". 900 строк нужного кода магическим образом улетучиваются в воздух. Как? Не врубаюсь.

Само собой, работоспособность селекторов проверял. И вот в чем мистика, страница может начать нормально кравлиться ни с того ни с сего. Я просто перезапускаю на локале один и тот же код и в какой-то момент времени все селекторы "включаются" и всё резко становится нормально. И тут приходится искать уже другую косячную страницу. Есть варианты в чем проблема?

Код минимального паука:`
    from scrapy import Request, Selector

```
PRODUCTS_SELECTOR = "//div[@class='b-showcase__item']//p[@class='b-showcase__item__link']/a/@href"
TITLE_SELECTOR = "//span[@class='b-product-detail__description']/text()"
MAC_TITLE_SELECTOR = "//h1[@class='product__name']/text()"
DIOR_TITLE_FIRST_SELECTOR = "//div[@class='b-product__item__item__title']/h1/text()"
DIOR_TITLE_SECOND_SELECTOR = "//div[@class='b-product__item__promo__title']/h1/text()"

class IleDeBeauteSpider(Spider):
    start_urls = ["http://iledebeaute.ru/shop/care/face/lips/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url=f'{url}?perpage=72', callback=self.parse, meta={'start_url': url})

    def parse(self, response):
        start_url = response.meta.get('start_url', None)
        page = response.meta.get('page', 1)

        if response.xpath(PRODUCTS_SELECTOR):
            yield Request(url=self.get_url(f'{start_url}page{page + 1}/?perpage=72'),
                          callback=self.parse, meta={'page': page + 1, 'start_url': start_url})

        for url in response.xpath(PRODUCTS_SELECTOR).extract():
            yield Request(url=self.get_url(url), callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):

        title = response.xpath(MAC_TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if not title:
            title = response.xpath(DIOR_TITLE_FIRST_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if not title:
            title = response.xpath(DIOR_TITLE_SECOND_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if not title:
            title = response.xpath(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if not title:
            print('This product has no title: ', response.url)
            yield {'url': response.url, 'error': 'no title'}`
```

Comment: еще не посмотрев код дам следующую рекомендацию: если попадается страница, из которой не удалось ничего достать - залогируйте весь ответ - код, заголовки, тело. UPD - по хорошему в методе parse надо проверять код ответа от сервера. Может вы страницы с 500 пытаетесь распрарсить, или с 403.

Comment: Всегда 200. Вот всегда. При чем никаких явных ошибок тоже не видно.

Comment: Зуб даёте?) но лучше все таки залогировать, и потом когда ошибка ещё раз появится разбираться с логами

Comment: Немного запоздало, но всё же расскажу что там было. Оказалось, что сервер отдавал кривой html и все нормальные парсеры ламали об него голову. Пришлось использовать корявый bs4 для разбора.